# HTTP Requests Fails for WordPress sites after upgrading from PHP 5.2 to PHP 5.3

Tags: wordpress, php53

I've upgraded from Ubuntu 9.10 to 10.04 beta 1 and PHP got upgraded from 5.2 to 5.3
Now all my WordPress & Magento sites arent working.
I tried retrieving the URL headers from the command line, but HTTP request fails.

Utilizing get_headers in a small script,
PHP Warning: get_headers(http://local.vhosts1.com): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! in get_headers.php on line 12

But HTTP request fails only for WordPress and Magento based sites - not custom written ones. Does this probably have to do with some htaccess directive ?

Answer (score 0):

Check the setting for:

```
allow_url_fopen = On
```

in your php.ini file.  It is possible that the code is not using sockets to open the remote sites and is using file_get_contents.

Comment: allow_url_fopen is already On in /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini